# Get data for belongs_to Two Parents rails 5

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, actionpack

I have a class like the following:

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :father
  belongs_to :mother
end
```

My goal is to create endpoints

- base-url/father/children #get all children for father
- base-url/mother/children #get all children for mother

I'm wondering what the correct way of nesting these resources would be I know I can do it one way like:

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  before action :set_father, only: %i[show] 
  def show
     @children = @father.children.all
    render json: @children
  end
...
```

But how can I get the same for base-url/mother/children, is this possible through nested resources?
I know I can code the routes.rb to point at a specific controller function if I need to but I would like to understand if I'm missing something, i'm unsure from reading the active record and action pack docs if I am.

Comment: In that case you should have an endpoint for father/children and other for mother/children, meaning two routes and two actions in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Implementation I went with is as follows:
My child controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:mother_id]
      @child = Mother.find_by(id: params[:mother_id]).blocks
      render json: @child
    elsif params[:father_id]
      @child = Father.find_by(id: params[:father_id]).blocks
      render json: @child
    else
      redirect_to 'home#index'
    end
  end
...
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :mother, only: [:index] do
    resources :child, only: [:index]
  end

  resources :father, only: [:index] do
    resources :child, only: [:index]
  end
...
```

- base_url/mother/{mother_id}/children #get all children for mother
- base_url/father/{father_id}/children #get all children for father